# Pixel offset in image from FLIR Lepton 3.5 VoSPI

Tags: esp32, thermal, c++

I´m working on my driver for a FLIR Lepton 3.5 thermal imaging sensor attached to an ESP32-S3I want to display the image on an LCD, but the image contains line offsets.

[image]

I use the following settings with the camera

- Test pattern ramp
- Auto resolution enable
- No AGC
- No telemetry

I guess the issue is in the VoSPI code because the remaining code is only a capture task that waits for VSync and some queue handling for the frame buffer.

**vospi.cpp**

```
#include <esp_log.h>
#include <esp_timer.h>
#include <esp_task_wdt.h>

#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "vospi.h"
#include "lepton.h"

/** @brief Packet number that contains the segment.
 */
#define VOSPI_PACKET_TTT                        20

static const char* TAG          = "VoSPI";

uint16_t Counter = 0;

/** @brief              Copy a received VoSPI packet into a buffer.
 *  @param p_Interface  Pointer to VoSPI interface object
 *  @param p_Buffer     Pointer to data buffer
 */
static void VoSPI_CopyPacketToBuffer(VoSPI_t* p_Interface, uint16_t* p_Buffer)
{
    uint16_t* Dst;

    Dst = &p_Buffer[((p_Interface->Internal.CurrentSegment - 1) * p_Interface->Internal.WordsPerSegment) + (p_Interface->Internal.CurrentPacket * (LEPTON_VOSPI_WIDTH / 2))];

    // NOTE: The camera is transmitting the data in MSB first. So we need to flip them.
    // NOTE: We have to skip the first four bytes because they contain the packet header.
    for(uint32_t i = 4; i < LEPTON_VOSPI_PACKET_LENGTH; i += sizeof(uint16_t))
    {
        uint16_t Data = 0;

        Data = (static_cast<uint16_t>(p_Interface->Internal.Buffer[i]) << 8) | p_Interface->Internal.Buffer[i + 1];
        *Dst++ = Data;
    }
}

Lepton_Error_t VoSPI_Init(VoSPI_t* p_Interface, bool UseTelemetry)
{
    Lepton_Error_t Error;

    if(p_Interface == NULL)
    {
        return LEPTON_ERR_INVALID_ARG;
    }
    else if(p_Interface->Internal.isInitialized)
    {
        return LEPTON_ERR_OK;
    }

    if(spi_bus_initialize(p_Interface->Host, &p_Interface->Master, p_Interface->DMA) != ESP_OK)
    {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Lepton SPI Master initialization failed!");

        Error = LEPTON_ERR_FAIL;
        goto VoSPI_Init_Error_1;
    }

    if(spi_bus_add_device(p_Interface->Host, &p_Interface->Interface, &p_Interface->Internal.Handle) != ESP_OK)
    {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to add Lepton SPI device!");

        Error = LEPTON_ERR_FAIL;
        goto VoSPI_Init_Error_1;
    }
    
    p_Interface->Internal.Buffer = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(heap_caps_malloc(LEPTON_VOSPI_PACKET_LENGTH, MALLOC_CAP_DMA));
    if(p_Interface->Internal.Buffer == NULL)
    {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to allocate Lepton DMA packet buffer!");

        Error = LEPTON_ERR_NO_MEM;
        goto VoSPI_Init_Error_2;
    }

    memset(&p_Interface->Internal.Transaction, 0, sizeof(spi_transaction_t));

    p_Interface->Internal.Transaction.tx_buffer = NULL;
    p_Interface->Internal.Transaction.rx_buffer = p_Interface->Internal.Buffer;
    p_Interface->Internal.Transaction.rxlength = LEPTON_VOSPI_PACKET_LENGTH * 8;
    p_Interface->Internal.CurrentSegment = 1;
    p_Interface->Internal.isInitialized = true;

    VoSPI_UseTelemetry(p_Interface, UseTelemetry);

    return LEPTON_ERR_OK;

VoSPI_Init_Error_2:
    spi_bus_remove_device(p_Interface->Internal.Handle);

VoSPI_Init_Error_1:
    spi_bus_free(p_Interface->Host);

    return Error;
}

Lepton_Error_t VoSPI_Deinit(VoSPI_t* p_Interface)
{
    if(p_Interface == NULL)
    {
        return LEPTON_ERR_INVALID_ARG;
    }
    else if(p_Interface->Internal.isInitialized == false)
    {
        return LEPTON_ERR_OK;
    }

    spi_bus_remove_device(p_Interface->Internal.Handle);
    spi_bus_free(p_Interface->Host);

    if(p_Interface->Internal.Buffer != NULL)
    {
        heap_caps_free(p_Interface->Internal.Buffer);
    }

    return LEPTON_ERR_OK;
}

/** @brief              Read a packet from the Lepton.
 *                      Each video packet contains data for a single video line or telemetry line.
 *                      In addition to video packets, the VoSPI protocol includes discard packets that are provided when no video packets are available.
 *  @param p_Interface  Pointer to VoSPI interface object
 *  @return             LEPTON_ERR_OK when successful
 */
static Lepton_Error_t VoSPI_ReadPacket(VoSPI_t* p_Interface)
{
    uint8_t Segment;

    if(p_Interface == NULL)
    {
        return LEPTON_ERR_INVALID_ARG;
    }

    Segment = 0;

    // Receive a segment from the camera.
    if(spi_device_polling_transmit(p_Interface->Internal.Handle, &p_Interface->Internal.Transaction) == ESP_OK)
    {
        // The packet is invalid when the first byte of the ID contains "xF" (see datasheet page 48).
        if((p_Interface->Internal.Buffer[0] & 0x0F) != 0x0F)
        {
            // Get the packet number.
            p_Interface->Internal.CurrentPacket = p_Interface->Internal.Buffer[1];

            // The TTT bits of packet 20 contains the segment number in the four highest bits (see datasheet page 56).
            // ... 0TTT PPPP PPPPPPPP ...
            if(p_Interface->Internal.CurrentPacket == VOSPI_PACKET_TTT)
            {
                Segment = (p_Interface->Internal.Buffer[0] >> 4) & 0x07;
            }

            // Segment 0 indicates an invalid segment. So we have to discard it.
            if(Segment != 0)
            {
                p_Interface->Internal.CurrentSegment = Segment;
                ESP_EARLY_LOGD(TAG, "Seg: %u", Segment);
            }

            return LEPTON_ERR_OK;
        }
    }

    return LEPTON_ERR_FAIL;
}

Lepton_Error_t VoSPI_GetFrame(VoSPI_t* p_Interface, Lepton_Buffer_t* p_Buffer)
{
    uint32_t Now;
    uint16_t* Dst;

    if((p_Interface == NULL) || (p_Buffer == NULL))
    {
        return LEPTON_ERR_INVALID_ARG;
    }

    p_Buffer->Image_Valid = false;
    Now = esp_timer_get_time();
    Dst = p_Buffer->Image_Buffer;
    while(true)
    {
        esp_task_wdt_reset();

        if(VoSPI_ReadPacket(p_Interface) == LEPTON_ERR_OK)
        {
            VoSPI_CopyPacketToBuffer(p_Interface, Dst);

            if((p_Interface->Internal.CurrentSegment == 4) && (p_Interface->Internal.CurrentPacket == (p_Interface->Internal.PacketsPerSegment - 1)))
            {
                return LEPTON_ERR_OK;
            }
        }

        if((esp_timer_get_time() - Now) > LEPTON_MAX_WAIT_TIME_US)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return LEPTON_ERR_TIMEOUT;
}

void VoSPI_UseTelemetry(VoSPI_t* p_Interface, bool Enable)
{
    if(p_Interface == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    if(Enable)
    {
        //TBD
    }
    else
    {
        p_Interface->Internal.WordsPerSegment = 4800;
        p_Interface->Internal.PacketsPerSegment = 60;
    }
}
```

**application.cpp**

```
 Error = Lepton_GetFrameBuffer(&_Device, &FrameBuffer);
if(Error == LEPTON_ERR_OK)
{
    Lepton_SceneStatistics_t Statistics;

    Lepton_GetSceneStatistics(&_Device, &Statistics);

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Min. intensity: %i", Statistics.MinIntensity);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Max. intensity: %i", Statistics.MaxIntensity);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Mean intensity: %i", Statistics.MeanIntensity);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Pixels: %u", Statistics.Pixels);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Pixel 1: %u", FrameBuffer.Image_Buffer[0]);

    for(uint16_t y = 0; y < DISPLAY_ROWS; y++)
    {
        for(uint16_t x = 0; x < DISPLAY_COLUMNS; x++)
        {
            Display_Pixel_t Pixel;
            uint16_t Data = FrameBuffer.Image_Buffer[((y >> 1) * 160) + (x >> 1)];

            Pixel.R = (Data & 0xF800) >> 11;
            Pixel.G = (Data & 0x7E0) >> 5;
            Pixel.B = (Data & 0x1F);

            Display_AddPixel(Pixel, x, y);
        }
    }
    Display_Flush();
}

Lepton_Error_t Lepton_GetFrameBuffer(Lepton_t* p_Device, Lepton_Buffer_t* p_Buffer, uint32_t Timeout)
{
    if((p_Device == NULL) || (p_Buffer == NULL))
    {
        return LEPTON_ERR_INVALID_ARG;
    }
    else if(p_Device->Internal.isInitialized == false)
    {
        return LEPTON_ERR_NOT_INITIALIZED;
    }
    else if(p_Device->Internal.Task.Handle == NULL)
    {
        return LEPTON_ERR_INVALID_STATE;
    }

    if(xQueueReceive(p_Device->FB.Queue, p_Buffer, Timeout / portTICK_PERIOD_MS) == pdPASS)
    {
        return LEPTON_ERR_OK;
    }

    return LEPTON_ERR_FAIL;
}
```

I don´t find any explanation for this issue.